# Why is my bean set null after marking the @PreAuthorize method?

Tags: java, spring

I have only one controller, where Spring set null in my service.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserServiceImpl userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PutMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN')")
    private ResponseEntity<ResultDto<UserDto>> updateUser(@RequestBody UserUpdateDto userUpdateDto) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResultDto<>(userService.updateUser(userUpdateDto)));
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    private ResponseEntity<ResultDto<UserDto>> getUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResultDto<>(userService.findById(id)));

    }

    ...
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    ...
}
```

When I make a request with this configuration I get userServie == null

If I remove @PreAuthorize everything will work fine. What could it be?

Comment: How exactly do you see `userService` being null? Do you get a `NullPointerException`? If so, can you please share the stack trace?

Comment: I get java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.site.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.findById(java.lang.Long)" because "this.userService" is null at com.example.site.rest.UserController.getUserById(UserController.java:37) ~classes/:na]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You should autowire (in your constructor of UserController) UserService (interface) instead of actual implementation.

Second, do you have any other implementation of UserService interface? If not, get rid of that interface. This boilerplate is imho anti-pattern. If you will need to provide second implementation, there is an exact point of a time, where you will create your interface.

Check, if you really want to use hasAnyAuthority and not hasAnyRole.

Last what came to my mind, do you have these annotations on your configuration?:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

PS: Why do you not use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` also on your controller? It has an parameter to put Autowired annotation on created constructor if you need. And if there is only single constructor, spring will do autowiringby default. No need to annotation.

Comment: Yes, I have one implementation of UserService, perhaps this is an antipattern, but it does not depend on the problem.

I of course use the '''@EnableWebSecurity''' annotation.

I use @RequiredArgsConstructor everywhere, changed it here for degug.

My logic is tied to GrandetAuthorities

Also UserService extends UserDetailService, perhaps this will give more information.

In general, such cases have never happened in the last 2 years.

Comment: Try to use attribute autowiring (instead of constructor). Because preauthorize uses AOP, there is a chance that you use your bean somehow directly instead of using injected proxy class.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is to rewrite from PreAuthorize to the configuration

In my case it's:

```
httpSecurity
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(cors()))
            .sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer ->
                    httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                    .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/users/{id}").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users").hasAuthority("TEACHER")
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users/groups/{id}").hasAuthority("TEACHER")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .apply(new JwtTokenConfig(jwtTokenProvider));
```

But the problem with PreAuthorize remains open (I didn’t want to solve this problem this way)